# Was my inference regarding $u(z)=log(z)$ correct?

Tags: functions, optimization, game-theory, economics

I have already solved the problem but would appreciate a clarification in part (b).

*A* has initial wealth $w$ and faces a loss $l$ with known probability $\pi$. Insurance
available at unit price $\rho$ will provide unit compensation $1$ if the loss occurs. (Assume
that 0 < $\pi$; $\rho$ < 1) Denote by $x$ the quantity of insurance purchased, and suppose
that this quantity can be no smaller than $0$ (no insurance) and no larger than $l$ (full
insurance). Write $u(.)$ for *A's* utility index function over money lotteries.

**(a)** Express *A's* utility as a function of the choice variable $x$ and the parameters
$w, l, \pi$, and $\rho$.

My answer:

[image]

**(b)** Suppose that $u(z) = log z$.

If $\rho = \pi$ , what will be
A's demand for insurance? How will this demand change if instead $\rho >\pi$?
$\:$
If $\rho < \pi$?

**My question**: I'm not too sure what bearing $u(z)=log(z)$ has on the actual problem, could anyone explain?

This is what I did (FOC for optimality) :

[image]
[image]

As it turns out, my answer for **(b)** is correct.
If I remember correctly $u(z)=log(z)$ should represent a risk averse function. However, I still don't understand what role $u(z)=log(z)$ is supposed to play in part **(b)** as I achieved the correct answer by coincidence.

$$\:$$
I.e. I treated $u(z)=log(z)$ as $u(x)=log(x)$ and just went about finding the FOC for $U(x)$.

Comment: Sorry guys, I know that the format of the question was bad, I will try to post an image instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your FOC is **wrong** if the utility is different than $u(z)=\log(z)$. For example, consider $$u(x)=\sqrt{x}$$ then your FOC is:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}U(x)=\frac{\pi (1-p)}{2\sqrt{w-\ell+x(1-p)}}-\frac{(1-\pi)p}{2\sqrt{w-px}}=0$$

Your FOC makes sense only if $u^\prime(x)=\frac 1x$.